# Fun with array of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm a total Perl newb, but still cannot believe I cannot figure this out with all the info I've read through online, but, I've burned too much time and am suffering from block at this point.  Hoping to learn something based on my real life example...

Ok, I think I have an array of arrays, created like this:

```
my @array1 = ();
my @array2 = ();
my $ctr1 = 0;
my $col;
[sql query]
while(($col)=$sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
  $array1[$ctr1]=$col;
  $ctr1++;
}

print STDERR "@array1";

##results in 10 rows, a mac address in each
##00:00:00:00:00:00 00:11:11:11:11:11 22:22:22:22:22:22 33:33:33:33:33:33 ...
```

Now I do another query.  While looping through results, I am looking for those 10 mac addresses.  When I find one, I add a row to array2 with the mac and the sequential number accumulated to the point, like this:

```
[sql query]
while(($col)=$sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
  $ctr2++;
  if( my ($matched) = grep $_ eq $col, @array1 ) {
    push( @array2, ($col,$ctr2) );
  }
}

print STDERR "@array2";

##results in 10 rows, a mac address and an integer in each
##00:00:00:00:00:00 2 00:11:11:11:11:11 24 22:22:22:22:22:22 69 33:33:33:33:33:33 82 ...
```

Now the easy part.  I want to loop through array2, grabbing the mac address to use as part of a sql query.  Therein lies the problem.  I am so ignorant as to exactly what I am doing that even though I had it almost working, I can't get back to that point.  Ignorance is definitely not bliss.

When I loop through array2, I am getting a host of errors, based on the different forms of the statement.  The one I think is right is listed below along with the error message...

```
my $ctr3 = 0;
foreach $ctr3 (@array2) {
  my $chkmac = $array2[$ctr3][0];    <--- gacks here with the error below - line 607
  [SQL query]


[Thu May 30 14:05:09 2013] [error] Can't use string ("00:66:55:77:99:88") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /path/to/test.cgi line 607.\n
```

I believe the issue is that my array of arrays is not an array of arrays.  If it were, it would work as coded, or so I think from the reading...  That said, I cannot fathom what I am dealing with otherwise.  This will be a head slapper I'm all but sure, but I am stumped....  Little help, please?

TIA
O

Comment: If you're not sure what data structure you've ended up with -- and this isn't unusual if you're not used to Perl's datastructures! -- the excellent Data::Dumper module can be used to visualise what you've ended up with. Just `use Data::Dumper;`, and `print Dumper( \@my_array );`

Comment: `I'm a total Perl newb, but still cannot believe I cannot figure this out` - I've used Perl for years, but that still happens to me far more often than I like to admit

Comment: Take a look at the [Perl tutorials](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html). There's one that's called [Mark's very short tutorial about references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) that will really, really explain how references work. The only problem is that once you read it, your understanding of references will become so clear that you'll be using the most convoluted and hard to maintain references. The solution to that is to read the very excellent [Object Oriented Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html). Fun is just a click away!

Comment: I definitely flitted with the Data::Dumper and will get that loaded sometime soon...  I'll check out those tuts.  Lord knows I've read enough of them.  Sometimes it actually becomes counterproductive, there is so much stuff available...  On, On!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an array of arrays you want to use an array reference, e.g.

```
 push @array2, [$col, $ctr2];
```

When accessing an element within an array refernce, you'll want to use the `->` operator. Also, when looping through an array, it's not necessary to index back into that same array. So the last part would look more like:

```
foreach $ctr3 (@array2) {
    my $chkmac = $ctr3->[0];
    ....
```

Comment: Good catch; I missed the push issue.

Comment: Push issue?  I thought that was the same.  I see the difference now.  I kept trying to make the square brackets work, but I never dreamed the parenthesis were the issue.  I never saw a single example withot them!!  Let's give this another try...

Comment: Eureka!  Funny how it works when you do it right!  Thank you gents both so much.  I really appreciate your assistance and free lesson!  :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do the `foreach` there, `$ctrl3` won't have the index in it, it'll have the value. So you should just need to do `$ctrl3->[0]`. Note the `->` which dereferences the array reference (`@array2` is actually an array of array references).

EDIT: As AKHolland pointed out, `@array2` actually isn't an array of array references, although that's what it should be. You also need to change:

```
push( @array2, ($col, $ctr2) );
```

To

```
push( @array2, [$col, $ctr2] );
```

This makes an array reference, rather than a list. A list in this context just collapses down into regular arguments to `push`, meaning you're pushing two separate strings into `@array2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that your array of arrays is not an array of arrays, since in Perl there is no such thing.  So what do you have instead?  There's two ways to see.

First, when you print `@array2`, you come up with a string composed of alternating MACs and counts, separated by spaces.  Since the spaces sort-of-signify the division between array elements, we might surmise that what we've got is a single array of heterogeneous elements, such that element 0 is a MAC, element 1 is a count, element 2 is another MAC, and so on.

The other perspective is to look at how `@array2` is constructed:

```
push( @array2, ($col,$ctr2) );
```

From [the documentation for `push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html), we find that `push ARRAY LIST` works by appending the elements of `LIST` to the end of `ARRAY`.  This has the effect of flattening the list into the array such that its original identity as a list is lost.  You can add all the parentheses you want, when Perl expects a list it flattens all of them away.

So how do you achieve the effect you want?  [The List-of-Lists documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) has a detailed treatment, but the short answer is that you make a list of array references.  Array references are scalars and are therefore legal elements in an array.  But they retain their identify as array references!

The anonymous array reference constructor is the square bracket `[]`.  In order to push an array reference containing the elements `$col` and `$ctr2` onto the end of `@array2`, you simply do this:

```
push( @array2, [$col, $ctr2] );
```

The code you wrote for accessing a particular element of the array-reference-in-an-array now works.  But since I've already written a bunch of paragraphs on the subject, let me finish by explaining what was wrong originally and how changing the `push` statements suddenly makes it work.

The expression `$array2[$ctr3][0]` is sometimes written as `$array2[$ctr3]->[0]` to clarify what it's actually doing.  What it does is to take the value of `$array2[$ctr3]` and treat it as an array reference, taking its 0 element.  If we take `$ctr3` to be `0` (as it would be at the top of the loop) the value of `$array2[$ctr3]` is the first element, `00:00:00:00:00:00`.  When you then subsequently ask Perl to treat `00:00:00:00:00:00` as an array reference, Perl dies because it doesn't know how to treat a string as an array reference.

When instead the value of `$array2[$ctr3]` is an array reference because that is what you pushed onto `@array2` when constructing it, Perl is able to do as you ask, dereferencing the array reference and looking at element 0 of the resulting array, whose value happens to be `00:00:00:00:00:00`.